# Higher Dijkgraaf-Witten Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, gauge-theory, topological-field-theory

I am trying to understand higher-form symmetries in TQFT. In particular the higher-form version of Dijkgraaf-Witten Theory.

It is known that for a 0-form symmetry we can specify the principal G-bundle through homotopy classes of the classifying map
$$ M \rightarrow BG = K(G,1). $$
This is known from Homotopy Theory and Eilenberg-MacLan spaces. Indeed the homotopy classes of these maps are in bijection with the first cohomology group $H^1(M,G)$ that for a finite group is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(M),G)$ and fit the usual gauge theory:
$$ [M,K(G,1)] \simeq H^1(M,G) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(M),G) $$

I cannot find any reference for a higher version of this. Should I expect a naive generalization? This is motivated by the fact that for a 1-form symmetry $H^2(M,G)$ works as a straightforward generalization to the previous case. But does homotopy theory tell me something about the classification of gerbes via classifying maps?

---

There is a [follow-up question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/736749/dijkgraaf-witten-for-a-2-group) to this, when the symmetry structure is an honest 2-group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Higher-form symmetries are abelian so, with $G$ a discrete abelian group and $p\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ (or $G$ a discrete group, not necessarily abelian, if $p=0$):
$$ [M, K(G,p+1)] \cong \mathrm{H}^{p+1}(M;G) \cong \operatorname{Hom}\left(\pi_{p+1}(M),G\right) $$
and everything works as it should.
See e.g. [the Wikipedia page for Eilenberg-McLane spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93MacLane_space#Bijection_between_homotopy_classes_of_maps_and_cohomology) or the paper [From gauge to higher gauge models of topological phases](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.10104) by Delcamp and Tiwari$^{(*)}$.

---

$^{(*)}$In that paper they do not explicitly mention $K(G,p+1)$, but they define it descriptively as a higher-classifying space $B^{p+1}G$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, that article is terribly clear.

Comment: I have added the natural next question. I’d gladly hear if you have something to say about it.

Comment: @Badillo You should not edit the question to ask a further question in a way that invalidates the existing answer, see e.g. [this physics-meta SE thread](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4147/should-we-disallow-vast-self-editing-of-a-question-completely-changing-its-me). What you should do, instead, is revert to the previous state of the question and ask your new question in a new thread (linking this question, if it's related).